# The element is not declared while importing schemas

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlreader

I am getting The 'http://TruncatePOC.Schema2:Root' element is not declared error while validating schema.

Below is the code :

```
           XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
         settings.XmlResolver = new XmlXsdResolver();
            //   create a validating reader
            schema =   XmlSchema.Read(schemaStream,null);                

            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
            settings.IgnoreComments = true;
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes;                
            settings.Schemas.Add(schema);                
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);

            reader = XmlReader.Create(partStream, settings);
```

Can any one please help me on this

Thanks

Comment: Please post the schema which is failing validation

Comment: Make sure you are using the same version of schema as the xml.  The error indicates one of your properties is not in the schema which may be acceptable.  Many schema allow optional properties and you may just be using an optional parameter.